# Error "not numeric" when using crosstalk package with EnhancedVolcano

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, bioconductor, ggplotly

I'd like to implement a cross-talk functionality between a table and plot in both directions:

1. select the row in the table which will be reflected in the plot
2. select a dot in the plot which will be reflected in the table. Same idea as [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/215948_95c1ab86ad334d2f82856d9e5ebc16af.html).

I've managed to implement a script, which works beautifully if I make scatter plot with `ggplot()` and  table (both objects cross-talk!). However, when used `EnhancedVolcano()` and table I got the following error:

```
Error in EnhancedVolcano(toptable = data_shared, lab = "disp", x = "qsec",  : 
  qsec is not numeric!
```

If I replace `data_shared` variable with `df_orig`, no error is raised, but there is no cross-talking between objects :(

Does this mean that `SharedData$new()` doesn't recognize numeric values as numeric? How to fix this error?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Toy example:

```
  library(plotly)            # '4.9.1'
  library(DT)                # '0.11'
  library(crosstalk)         # ‘1.0.0’
  library(EnhancedVolcano)   # ‘1.4.0’
  # Input
  data1 = mtcars  #dim(data1)  # 32  11
  data_shared = SharedData$new(data1) #, key = c("qsec", "hp"))
  # df_orig = data_shared$origData()
  # V-Plot
  vp =EnhancedVolcano( toptable = data_shared,
                       lab  = 'disp',
                       x  =  'qsec',
                       y  =  'hp',
                       xlab  ='testX',
                       ylab = 'testY') 
  bscols(
    ggplotly(vp + aes(x= qsec, y= -log10(hp/1000))),
    datatable(data_shared, style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
              options=list(deferRender=FALSE, dom='t')))
```

Same script, which works with `ggplot()`:

```
data1 = mtcars  #dim(data1)  # 32  11
data_shared = SharedData$new(data1) 
vp = ggplot(data = data_shared, mapping = aes(qsec, hp)) +
  geom_point()
bscols(
  ggplotly(vp) ,
  datatable(data_shared, style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
            options=list(deferRender=FALSE, dom='t')))
```

Comment: Hey I am afraid EnhancedVolcano is a big wrapper around many ggplot2 functions and doesn't support crosstalk... Either you hack the EnhancedVolcano function or you write the volcano plot using ggplot2...

Comment: ohhh nooo!!! what a bummer !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Related (same) question was [posted at BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/p/421750/#421769), and the package author posted an answer, with author's permission copying an answer here:

---

Hi,

Thanks - that's very useful code and I may add it to the main package vignette, eventually.

I tried it here on my computer and I was able to get it working in my browser, but some components of the original plot seem to have been lost. I think that you just need to convert your column, '*qsec*', to numerical values.

Re-using an example from my [Vignette](https://github.com/kevinblighe/EnhancedVolcano#highlighting-key-variables-via-custom-point-sizes), here is a perfectly reproducible example:

```
  library("pasilla")
  pasCts <- system.file("extdata", "pasilla_gene_counts.tsv",
    package="pasilla", mustWork=TRUE)
  pasAnno <- system.file("extdata", "pasilla_sample_annotation.csv",
    package="pasilla", mustWork=TRUE)
  cts <- as.matrix(read.csv(pasCts,sep="\t",row.names="gene_id"))
  coldata <- read.csv(pasAnno, row.names=1)
  coldata <- coldata[,c("condition","type")]
  rownames(coldata) <- sub("fb", "", rownames(coldata))
  cts <- cts[, rownames(coldata)]
  library("DESeq2")
  dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = cts,
    colData = coldata,
    design = ~ condition)

  featureData <- data.frame(gene=rownames(cts))
  mcols(dds) <- DataFrame(mcols(dds), featureData)
  dds <- DESeq(dds)
  res <- results(dds)

  library(EnhancedVolcano)
  p1 <- EnhancedVolcano(res,
    lab = rownames(res),
    x = "log2FoldChange",
    y = "pvalue",
    pCutoff = 10e-4,
    FCcutoff = 2,
    xlim = c(-5.5, 5.5),
    ylim = c(0, -log10(10e-12)),
    pointSize = c(ifelse(res$log2FoldChange>2, 8, 1)),
    labSize = 4.0,
    shape = c(6, 6, 19, 16),
    title = "DESeq2 results",
    subtitle = "Differential expression",
    caption = "FC cutoff, 1.333; p-value cutoff, 10e-4",
    legendPosition = "right",
    legendLabSize = 14,
    col = c("grey30", "forestgreen", "royalblue", "red2"),
    colAlpha = 0.9,
    drawConnectors = TRUE,
    hline = c(10e-8),
    widthConnectors = 0.5)

  p1 <- p1 +
    ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-6, 6)) +
    ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
      breaks=seq(-6,6, 1))

  library(plotly)
  library(DT)
  library(crosstalk)  

  bscols(
    ggplotly(p1 + aes(x= log2FoldChange, y= -log10(pvalue))),
      datatable(
        data.frame(res),
        style="bootstrap",
        class="compact", width="100%",
        options=list(deferRender=FALSE, dom='t')))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, *plotly* and/or *bscols* don't like the use of `bquote()`, so, one cannot have the fancy axes names that I use in *EnhancedVolcano*:

```
... + xlab(bquote(~Log[2] ~ "fold change")) + ylab(bquote(~-Log[10] ~ italic(P)))
```

When i try to add these, it throws an error.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

tried to modify few things in volcano function, got following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(toptable) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("SharedData", "R6")’ to a data.frame
```

not sure yet, how to fix it.